# Rewriting default azurewebsites to custom domains

Tags: c#, azure, swagger, azure-web-app-service

I have few web apps (REST service that uses swagger)) hosted on Azure with their default domains as https://xyz-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index.
I need to rewrite them to custom domain (already exists) , example: newdomain.net
I tried the adding the following to web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect requests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xyz\.azurewebsites\.net$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://newdomain.net/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>     
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This code redirects to newdomain.net, however if I try to do *newdomain.net/swagger*, it would throw the 404 error.
I'm new to doing this.

What should be my correct approach so that instead of using https://xyz-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index, I should be able to use https://newdomain.net/xyz-test/swagger/ui/index to make API calls

(note: mydomain.com will be used by more than one service. 
example: https://newdomain.net/abc-test/swagger/ui/index)

Answer (score 0):

You need to point mydomain.com to the Azure web site with a CNAME DNS record. To do this, see this link: [Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

Once the CNAME is in place (and propagated in DNS), you can manage different web apps with different path.

Moreover, if you want fine grained path/url management, you can use an [Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/) to route specific url or path using multi-site listeners.